# Run rake assets:precompile before tests that include :js tag and skip otherwise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

tl;dr --

*Is it possible to run a single command (e.g. `rake assets:precompile` ) only when there is a `:js` test included in the body of tests being run?*

--

I'm developing a rails 5, ruby 2.3.1 app that has a large `rspec` test suite.

We recently installed the `webpacker` gem in the application which has caused us to have to run:

`$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

before running the tests. If the above command is not run the tests will be run against the most recently precompiled assets.

This has caused some headaches as developers have forgotten this step and then banged their heads against a wall until someone remembers to run that before running the test suite.

Ideally I'd like to simply add to the `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
config.before(:suite) do
  system('bundle exec rake assets:precompile')
end
```

However, this will run the precompile before every single run of the test suite or any subset therein. This will drastically slow down development time for a backend dev that is simply trying to run a single request spec that normally takes 0.15 seconds.

Additionally, we normally skip running the `:js` tests when developing with `guard` as they take too long. We just run the `:js` specs as a sanity check before deploying or pushing to a remote branch.

Unfortunately, adding the `{:js => true}` option to:

```
config.before(:suite, js:true)
```

doesn't work either, as options are ignored for the `before(:suite)`.

Comment: you could make sure to run your feature tests separately from other tests and define separate commands in the first instance for each type of tests so developer would know which may have js-related tests which don't.

Comment: I agree with @hyphenbash. Use rspec [tags](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-6/docs/command-line/tag-option) so you can run specific types of tests together (`bundle exec rspec --tag type:js`),  then [only run it for those tags](https://gist.github.com/linjunpop/4367228).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Filter using `:js` tag and run once for all specs.

```
  ENV[ 'ASSET_PRECOMPILE_DONE' ] = nil

  config.before(:each, :js) do
    if ! ENV[ 'ASSET_PRECOMPILE_DONE' ]
      system 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile'
      ENV[ 'ASSET_PRECOMPILE_DONE' ] = 'true'
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is great. Note that if you're not using webpacker (like me) you can add `npm install` before the precompile command, so that the rails pipeline picks up the bundled output from webpack. Thanks for this.

Comment: I like this too because you can set the environment variable for the automated environments that already precompile beforehand so your test times aren't affected. Note that your first `js` test will report as having run longer due to the asset precompile time.